# update empty value in a list

Tags: python, list

so i have a text file as shown below:

```
a,b,
```

i want to update the empty value in the list, here is my attempt:

```
def test():
    z=""
    with open("test.txt","r") as user_file:
        for line in user_file.readlines():
            z = line.split(",")
            print(z)
            print(z[2])
    if z[2] not in["1","2","3"]:
        z[2] =="1"
        level = 1
        with open("test.txt","w") as x:
            x=x.write(str(z))
        return level
    else:
        level = z[2]
        return level
x=test()
print(x)
```

here are the result:

```
if z[2] not in["1","2","3"]:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

i want to overide the txt file only the [2] part only

Comment: give some value to z. say `z=""`

Comment: at whr? before the def or inside the def?

Comment: Read the error message! If `z` doesn't have 3 elements, you can't access `z[2]`. As the error message clearly states, it's out of range.

Comment: Since there are only two elements in `z` (`a` and `b`), the index of z can't exceed `1`. In python, index of list begins at `0`

Comment: It may be because there is no z[2], your text file have only two entres, z[0] and z[1]

Comment: Something is wrong here. Splitting `'a,b,'` should result in `['a','b','']` - are you sure that is the line?

Answer (score 0):

your `if z[2] not in["1","2","3"]` code is not indented inside the for loop.
this means that it sees the `z` variable setup to `""`, not the one that results from the `split`

please see https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html

Comment: I think you should clarify that, then. You think there's a blank line at the end of the file?

Comment: the test `if z[2] not in["1","2","3"]` runs on the global z, the one set to `""`, not on the result of `split`.


I updated the answer accordingly

Comment: I don't need to see anything, it's not my question. I'm asking you to clarify your answer.